# Latest date from date, month, year

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite DB with date, month, year fields in integers (I believe they should have used a date field but the choice wasn't mine). I would like to select the row whose date value is the latest. What is the best query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by year, month, `date` desc
limit 1
```